# minidump vs. fulldump?

Tags: .net, dump, crash-dumps, minidump

I just recently started looking at dump files to help me analyze crashes of the w3wp process on our production environment at work...

And I would like to know, what are the differences between a minidump and a fulldump file ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> #### Differences between full memory dump files and mini memory dump files
>
> A memory dump file can collect a variety of information. Typically, a
> support engineer must have all the contents of virtual memory to
> troubleshoot a problem. In other cases, you might want to capture less
> information to focus on a specific problem. The debugger is flexible.
> This flexibility lets you limit the information that a memory dump
> file captures by collecting either full memory dump files or mini
> memory dump files:
>
> - **Full memory dump files**. These files contain the
>   contents of virtual memory for a process. These files are the most
>   useful when you are troubleshooting unknown issues. A support engineer
>   can use these files to look anywhere in memory to locate any object,
>   pull up the variable that was loaded on any call stack, and
>   disassemble code to help diagnose the problem. The disadvantage of
>   full memory dump files is that they are large. It also may take
>   additional time to collect these files, and the process that is being
>   recorded must be frozen while the dump file is created.
> - **Mini memory
>   dump files**. A mini dump file is more configurable than a full dump
>   file and can range from only several megabytes (MB) up to the size of
>   a full dump file. The size differs because of the amount of virtual
>   memory that the debugger is writing to disk. Although you can gather
>   mini memory dump files quickly and they are small, they also have a
>   disadvantage. Mini dump files may contain much less information than
>   full dump files. The information that a mini dump file gathers may be
>   virtually useless to a support engineer if the area of memory that the
>   support engineer has to troubleshoot was not captured. For example, if
>   the heap memory is not written to the memory dump file, a support
>   engineer cannot examine the contents of a message that was being
>   processed at the time that the problem occurred. Useful information,
>   such as the subject line and the recipient list, would be lost.

An extract from [Microsoft's documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/8/b/b8b36faf-00f1-460f-b32b-98a20102da4e/MemoryDumpFileConceptsandProcesses.doc).

Answer (score 43):

Actually, as the following MS link states, things are bit more complex than suggested by the previous post.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/user-mode-dump-files#varieties

The difference between a mini-dump and a full-dump is more related to the format of the file than the amount of content/information in it. In fact, with the right configuration, a mini-dump will contain more information than a full-dump ever could and that is why properly configured mini-dumps are recommended in all cases.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The URL links to WinDBG document, which is the main tool to create dump on Windows system.

Comment: From the developer perspective a minidump is preferable, from a sysadmin perspective, a full dump is prefereable since the only way to create a "properly" configured minidump is with winDBG.  A system should be configured with either an automatic memory dump or a full memory dump