# Full crash dump vs. minidump?

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn, crash-dumps, minidump

currently my application creates full crash dumps via the registry settings in HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps" and DumpType 2.

Unfortunately these dumps often are very big. Now there is a thingy named "Minidump" available too. The MSDN-documentation is not very helpful here, it only says minidumps do not contain as much information as full crash dumps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/minidump-files

As the Windows documentation does not say what is exactly missing in Minidumps, my question: what is the difference to full dumps? Can I still use them to find the position of a crash within my application? Is the callstack contained as well as relevant symbol data to find the point in source when PDBs are available?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903329/minidump-vs-fulldump

Comment: Note that crash dumps often compress quite well.

Comment: Depends. Is it a language that compiles to native or IL?

Comment: @ThomasWeller C++ which builds native code

Comment: Did document in the first link answers your question?